# Result of DB facade gives error in $this->table Command: A row must be an array or a TableSeparator instance

Tags: php, laravel

I setup a Laravel-zero application and installed the database component.
I am using the `$this->table` function to show all "projects" which i am retrieving by `$projects = DB::table('projects')->get()->toArray();`
The only thing is that is giving an error: " A row must be an array or a TableSeparator instance.". But clearly the output is an array. What am i doing wrong?

Edit: output of $this->table($headers, []); is good.(to exclude problems)

Laravel docs is using toArray() aswell:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#defining-input-expectations

`$users = App\User::all(['name', 'email'])->toArray();`

My handle():

```
$headers = ['id','name', 'created_at', 'deleted_at'];
$projects = DB::table('projects')->get()->toArray();
$this->table($headers, $projects);
```

output of my array:

```
array:3 [
  0 => {#270
    +"id": "1"
    +"name": "TestProject"
    +"created_at": null
    +"updated_at": null
  }
  1 => {#272
    +"id": "2"
    +"name": "Testproject2"
    +"created_at": null
    +"updated_at": null
  }
  2 => {#273
    +"id": "3"
    +"name": "Nanko TEST"
    +"created_at": null
    +"updated_at": null
  }
]
```

Comment: The only thing that comes to my head right now is that `$projects` might be empty for whatever reason and therefore `null` or something.

Comment: The output is a dd(); of $projects

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it atm by looping true the collection and casting the objects to an array:

```
$array_projects = $projects->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return (array) $item;
});
```